# Has a pope ever been corrected publicly by a non-cleric in the presence of cardinals because of the unclear wording of a papal document?

Tags: catholicism, history, papacy

At the moment there is a lot of talk about four cardinals who have submitted a *dubia* to Pope Francis regarding the interpretation of *Amoris Laetitia.*

In one [article](http://www.catholicculture.org/news/headlines/index.cfm?storyid=30303) it stated that: "any 'fraternal correction' of the Pope should be made '*in camera caritatis,*' without a public statement."

This made me think of another question. Has a pope ever been publicly corrected or rebuked in front of cardinals by a non-cleric member of the Catholic Church?

What I mean by a non-cleric is a Catholic faithful who is not a deacon, priest, bishop or cardinal, but may be a layperson, nun or religious brother (not ordained).

**Post Script (Edit)**: In this question ([When did a “formal act of correction” of a pope's statement happen in the past?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/53739/when-did-a-formal-act-of-correction-of-a-popes-statement-happen-in-the-past)) which is similar, yet not a duplicate, the OP asks "when and who did it happen that the **bishops had to carry out the "formal correction"** in the history of the church?"

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It has happened to the present Pope.

Dr. Anca-Maria Cernea, Doctor at the Center for Diagnosis and Treatment-Victor Babes and President of the Association of Catholic Doctors of Bucharest (Romania) made the following speech to the Fourteenth Ordinary General Assembly of the Synod of Bishops, at which the Pope was present, on Friday 16 October 2015.

The doctor ["confronted the pope"](http://remnantnewspaper.com/web/index.php/fetzen-fliegen/item/2099-female-doctor-tells-pope-to-his-face-evil-in-this-world-comes-from-sin-not-from-income-disparity-or-climate-change) regarding his "inversion of priorities" in *Laudato Si',* saying "Evil in this world comes from sin, not from income disparity or 'climate change'."

> Your Holiness, Synod Fathers, Brothers and Sisters, I represent the Association of Catholic Doctors from Bucharest.
>
> I am from the Romanian Greek Catholic Church.
>
> ...
>
> Classical Marxism pretended to redesign society, through violent take-over of property.
>
> Now the revolution goes deeper; it pretends to redefine family, sex identity and human nature.
>
> This ideology calls itself progressive. But it is nothing else than the ancient serpent’s offer, for man to take control, to replace God, to arrange salvation here, in this world.
>
> It’s an error of religious nature, it’s Gnosticism.
>
> It’s the task of the shepherds to recognize it, and warn the flock against this danger.
>
> “Seek ye therefore first the Kingdom of God, and His justice, and all these things shall be added unto you.”
>
> The Church’s mission is to save souls. Evil, in this world, comes from sin. Not from income disparity or “climate change”.
>
> The solution is: Evangelization. Conversion.
>
> Not an ever increasing government control. Not a world government. These are nowadays the main agents imposing cultural Marxism to our nations, under the form of population control, reproductive health, gay rights, gender education, and so on.
>
> What the world needs nowadays is not limitation of freedom, but real freedom, liberation from sin. Salvation.
>
> ...
>
> Now we need Rome to tell the world: “Repent of your sins and turn to God for the Kingdom of Heaven is near”.
>
> Not only us, the Catholic laity, but also many Christian Orthodox are anxiously praying for this Synod. Because, as they say, if the Catholic Church gives in to the spirit of this world, it is going to be very difficult for all the other Christians to resist it.
>
> — Reported in [*LifeSiteNews*](https://www.lifesitenews.com/news/romanian-doctor-makes-blunt-powerful-plea-to-pope-and-bishops-in-presentati)

Comment: I have accepted your answer, but I do hope others will be able find different responses and examples for this question. I am sure there are more occasions than just this. Great answer and thank you.

Comment: @Ken There has been at least one other occasion with the present Pope; I remember the headlines, but can no longer find the news article. I believe other popes have been rather more circumspect with regard to the prior teachings of the Magisterium.