# Did any medieval Catholics believe in the possibility the repentance was possible immediately after death?

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, death, medieval-church, repentance

Did any [medieval](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_Ages) Catholics have a pious belief that immediately after death, God gave people a last chance to repent of their sins and thus save their immortal soul from going to hell for all eternity?

I recently came across the following tidbit about St. Padre Pio in which he affirmed his own belief that repentance immediately after death was possible.

> "I believe that not a great number of souls go to hell. God loves us so much. He formed us at his image. God loves us beyond understanding. And it is my belief that when we have passed from the consciousness of the world, when we appear to be dead, God, before He judges us, will give us a chance to see and understand what sin really is. And if we understand it properly, how could we fail to repent?" - [Close encounters of a special kind with Padre Pio: The Souls in Purgatory, The Guardian Angel, the devil.](https://caccioppoli.com/Close%20encounters%20of%20Padre%20Pio%20with%20deceased%20souls%20in%20Purgatory,%20Guardian%20Angel,%20devil.%20His%20own%20words%20on%20temptation,%20virtues,%20life..html)

This got me thinking of what a priest that once told me some years ago: “Some Catholics in the Middle Ages (500 AD - 1500 AD) had a pious belief that immediately after sinners had died, Our Lord gave them a final chance to repent!”

The priest in question is no longer amongst us and I have never known him to state something like this erroneously.

Can anyone find any references from any Catholic sources about the possible existence of this [pious belief](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=35592) during the Middle Ages?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think that Cardinal Cajetan speculated about that option.

Comment: @Thom I doubt it was Cdl. Cajetan (1469-1534); he was after Benedict XII's 1336 dogmatic definition (although Cdl. Cajetan was heterodox in his interpretation of the "exceptive clause" of Mt. 5:32 & 19:9).

Comment: @Geremia Joseph White, O.P. comments on this [here at 1:11:50](https://soundcloud.com/thomisticinstitute/what-is-the-nature-of-the-will-prof-edward-feser).

Comment: @SolaGratia I am not saying this is a tradition or that saints have held this pious belief. I am simply asking for reference dating from the Middle Ages on this subject matter.,

Comment: @Thom That opens the door to the possibility of demons repenting, too, but they are obstinate in evil ([I q. 62 a. 2](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP/FP064.html#FPQ64A2THEP1); cf. [Cajetan's long commentary on that article](https://archive.org/details/operaomniaiussui5thom/page/n142)).

Answer (score 1):

[John XXII (reigned 1316-1334) (in)famously held the opinion that one's particular judgment did not occur immediately after death.](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/53747/1787) His successor Benedict XII (reigned 1334-1342) defined the following dogma in [*Benedictus Deus*](https://www.papalencyclicals.net/ben12/b12bdeus.htm) (1336):

> we define that according to the general disposition of God, the souls of those who die in actual mortal sin go down into hell **immediately** (*mox*) after death and there suffer the pain of hell.

Thus, those who die in a state of mortal sin do not have a chance to repent after death.

Now that this dogma has been defined, it's not a pious opinion but heresy to hold a contrary view.

Comment: "Mox" often means "soon". What's your source for translating it "immediately" instead?

Comment: I know what the Church professes in this domain, but I am looking for a reference to the existence of a particular pious belief that some Catholics may have held during the Middle Ages.

Comment: @MattGutting Even if _mox_ isn't synonymous with _statim_ here, his statement still excludes repentance after death.

Comment: The [Middle Ages](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_Ages) extended from the 5th century to the 15th century. In other words it commenced 800 years before Pope Benedict XII reigned as Supreme Pontiff.

Comment: If [*mox* means "soon"](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=mox&highlight=mox) rather than "immediately" ([*statim*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=statim&highlight=statim)), the possibility seems to exist that the soul is judged at some short time after death, rather than immediately at death. That would leave open the possibility of repentance immediately after death, and judgment soon (*mox*) thereafter.

Comment: @MattGutting "_That would leave open the possibility of repentance immediately after death_" No. He affirms that "the souls of those who die in actual mortal sin go down into hell," regardless of how soon after death.

Comment: Note how the quote from Padre Pio still accords with this dogma "when we appear to be dead." What actually entails death is the soul's leaving the body. The soul may not be sensibly conscious, yet still in the body, and given to some sort of supernatural communion with God, in which it has a chance to finally repent.